# Count number of users logged in a day with timestamp in Kusto Query Language

Tags: kql

I am trying to get a list of number of users you have logged in a specific day listing the username and timestamp of when they logged in. Below is the query that I constructed:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
//|where timestamp > datetime(2021-03-01) and timestamp < datetime(2021-03-31)
| where user_AccountId !in ("sdasw", "gkhsksaauh", "dadwfa", "FREAD", "ReportBatch", "HSAIIF", "87383123hADHUQ++==", "GHDSQQU**++")
| where not(user_AccountId matches regex "^*@xxxxx-xxxx.net")
| where not(user_AccountId matches regex "^*@xxxxtool")
| where user_AccountId <> ""
| distinct user_AccountId
| summarize count()by user_AccountId
```

Below is the list that is generated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHTxo.png)

Comment: Please learn to use markdown in `Stackoverflow` to properly format your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "get **a list of number of users**" - do you want a list, or just the number. Since in your output I see you have the number, I assume you mean that you want the list of timestamps. If so, here's what you need to do:

Instead of

```
| summarize count() by user_AccountId
```

Try

```
| summarize make_list(timestamp) by user_AccountId
```

Comment: This is something which looks good, but any possible way to list the time when the users first logged in for the day?

Comment: Sure: | summarize make_list(timestamp), **min(timestamp)** by user_AccountId